# Check if mountpoint exists but file does not

Tags: android, file, synchronization, storage, google-drive-android-api

I am saving a list of files (absolute paths to a file). It can be of an internal storage or may be external storage.

While syncing those file to the Cloud (i.e. Google Drive), I am checking if file is exists or not at local(`File.exists()`), and if it does not delete it from the cloud.

But, when the external storage is not mounted, that is causing me to delete the file from the cloud. But, that should not happen. If the mount point is not available it should not check for the file. How can I check that condition?

For example, Files in the internal & external storage looks something like:

- Internal: `/storage/emulated/0/internal.txt`
- External: `/storage/4XXX-1234/Android/media/com.example/Documents/external.txt`

How can I check if storage is mounted only then check for the file existence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to find if file is on the mounted path or not.

```
File localFile = new File("/storage/4XXX-1234/Android/media/com.example/Documents/external.txt");

if(Environment.getExternalStorageState(new File(localFile.getAbsolutePath()))
         .equalsIgnoreCase("mounted"))) {
    Log.d(TAG,"File is on the mounted path");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the directory exists.

So for instance check first if directory `/storage/4XXX-1234` exists before use.

You can also check if directory `/storage/4XXX-1234/Android/media/com.example/Documents` exists before use.

```
String path = "/storage/4XXX-1234/Android/media/com.example/Documents/external.txt";

File file = new File (path);

if(!file.getParentFile().exists())
    return; // no dir. Not mounted
```

Comment: I am confused about the path I need to check? How much? Different devices will have different storage paths. Like, `/storage` or `/storage/4XXX-1234/` and so on.

Comment: Someone might delete the directory "Documents" but storage is mounted. Then scenario will fail.

Comment: The directory of your file is inthe path! Like in /storage/4XXX-1234/Android/media/com.example/Documents/external.txt.

Comment: If the file is actually deleted, then I need to delete it from the server. If the storage is not mounted, then only skipping the check. In the case for checking "Documents" folder, It will fail if the storage is mounted and Documents folder is deleted. It will not delete the file from the server

Comment: Well that is your problem too. You have then to decide what you want to do. We will not tell you what you have to do. The logic of your app is yours.

Comment: Thanks though for looking into it :)